# How to catch "History.Back" event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to catch "History.Back" event in JavaScript?
İ want to catch `history.back()` event and logout user.

P.s : There is some code about disabling `history.back()`, but is not useful for me.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
 function disableBackButton()
 {
   window.history.forward();
 }
 setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
</script>
```

then set `onunload` event

```
<body onunload="disableBackButton()">
```

Comment: Don't do this - reconsider your design instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch history back using "window.onpopstate" event. But AFAIK it is only available in HTML5.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-definitions-0

Comment: unfortunately to my knowledge, one can't distinguish the popstate event when going back in history from the popstate event when going forward. In addition, you won't receive this event on the page you're about to leave but only on the page where you arrive, which might not be under your control. It will be the same page only when the history entry was added manually via pushstate.