# How to go on previous page if i opened a page in another tab?

Tags: javascript, cookies, back, browser-history

Is it possible to go in previous page if i opened a page in another tab from search results (only using javascript or cookies)?

I have search page like test.com/search And search result like this:

```
 1) test.com/search/a
 2) test.com/search/b
 3) test.com/search/c
```

Now if i opened any of search result link in new tab `test.com/search/b` (will be in new tab and i want to go on `test.com/search` page)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, unless you hard code the back link to be a base_url or something like that, but then that would only lead you to the main page.

Comment: anyway as you said just use javascript and cookies, I think it's hard to do this. But if it's jsp page, you can store the data in session, because in 1 browser, all the tab of one site share the same session, so you can share data in several tabs.

Comment: @OQJF

It is ok for main question now what i want to do that if i am on URL google.com and paste my search result page test.com/search/b(it is search result page link) instead on google.com URL. Now is it possible to go back to test.com /search page URL instead of redirect google.com ?

Comment: hi, I'am not clear about your question. can you clarify it? you mean the opeartion is on the address bar of browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store text in cookies. You can redirect to different locations using javascript.

Write a cookie with the URL you're on, store it, let the user click on another page, [hook into the page back event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967414/how-to-catch-history-back-event-in-javascript), read the cookie and change the location to the URL you read from the cookie. It is also possible to manipulate the hash part of the URL using JavaScript and to store, for example, JSON encoded information in it. With that it is possible to have bookmarkable URLs which refer to a specific state. This is also used in [some](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange) [jQuery](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/ plugins.

However, hooking in the back button event is not possible without HTML5.

If you decide to depend on HTML5, you can [manipulate the browser history directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

Comment: It is ok for main question now what i want to do that if i am on URL google.com and paste my search result page test.com/search/b(it is search result page link) instead on google.com URL. Now is it possible to go back to test.com /search page URL instead of redirect google.com ?